# How do I increase the font size and set the page size when exporting a man page to PDF?

Tags: pdf, man

I know how to export a man page to PDF:

```
man -Tpdf cat > cat.pdf
```

What if I want to specify the page size (e.g. A4 or A5), and increase the font size (e.g. size 16)? How can I do it?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 and FreeBSD 12.2. I would prefer a solution that works on both systems, if possible.

---

Update: I have not found the answer, but I've found some clues:

- [Font size in man pages](https://www.reddit.com/r/groff/comments/asts02/font_size_in_man_pages/)

  Unfortunately, the suggested `-rS12` and/or `-rPS=12` options for Groff does not seem to have any effect on font size. I tried it on `/usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz` and `/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz` in Ubuntu.
- [[Groff] Is it possible to set base document font size larger than 12 poi](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff/2005-07/msg00064.html)

  Unfortunately, the "solution" doesn't seem to be applicable for man pages that don't have a `.TH` line in them (e.g. `/usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz` [dash's manual] in Ubuntu).